# Syntax to set several folders for helm-ag

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I have set up a function using helm-ag to search within a specific folder:

```
   (helm-ag "~/Documents/Dropbox/myfolder"))
```

However, would it be possible to add several folders where helm-ag would search simultaneously?
Thank you"